# How to combine inner element border with outer element border?

Tags: html, css

I have two elements: one is children of other:

```css
#main {
  display: flex
}
.out {
  height: 50px;
  border-right: 3px solid green;
}
.inner {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  border-right: 3px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="out">
    <div class="inner">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="out">
    <div class="inner">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="out">
    <div class="inner">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fcg6xty7/

As you can see, border of inner element and border of outer element are two different borders. I want that they were one border:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider declaring a `width` property with a `calc`<sup>[Ref - calc() MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)</sup> function to offset by `3px` (or at a value that suits any requirement).

Remember to declare `box-sizing: border-box`<sup>[Ref - box-sizing MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)</sup> in addition; to indicate to the browser to account for any border and padding in the value specified for `width` and `height`.

**Example:**

```
.inner {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-right: 3px solid red;
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: calc(100% + 3px); /* + value equal to the width of containing border*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
#main {
  display: flex
}

.out {
  height: 50px;
  border-right: 3px solid green;
}

.inner {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-right: 3px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: calc(100% + 3px); /* + value equal to the width of containing border*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="out">
    <div class="inner">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="out">
    <div class="inner">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="out">
    <div class="inner">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no he want both border to collapse, one above the other

Answer (score 3):

You can use a negative `margin-right` value to move the elements right:

```css
#main {
  display: flex
}
.out {
  height: 50px;
  border-right: 3px solid green;
}
.inner {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  border-right: 3px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-right: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="out">
    <div class="inner">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="out">
    <div class="inner">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="out">
    <div class="inner">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `position:relative` necessary in this context?

Comment: It seems there is a missing `;` on the `flex-grow` property. From what I can see, the only thing `position:relative` introduces is an ending `;` which opens up for the `margin-right`. It [should work without it](https://jsfiddle.net/fcg6xty7/4/), although not if you directly modify OP's CSS with the missing semi colon.

Comment: @agrm you are right. I changed my answer accordingly - thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Not my intention to be picky, @Johannes. At first I was mainly curious if it was intentional for cross browser compatibility or something in that lane :o)

Answer (score 1):

quick fix.. go for .. margin-right in negetive.

```
.inner {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  border-right: 3px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-right: -3px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably get away with it by simulating a border with box-shadow on the inner elements.

Delete the border, add

```
  box-shadow:  0 0 0 3px red;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/facundocorradini/tdqt8wum/

Adjust as needed.

If you only want a right-border, then leave the inner border as is, and use an inset box-shadow "border" on the outer element

```
.out {
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset -3px 0 0 green;
}
.inner {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  border-right: 3px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/facundocorradini/41y9pcw1/1/

By the way, you're setting flex-grow to the incorrect items, should be in the .out selector. Being in the .inner selectors it doesn't make anything, as the .inner are not flex-items (not childs from the flex container, but grand-children).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use **`:after`** pseudo selector for the green border. Check below snippet

```css
#main {
  display: flex
}

.inner:after {
  content: "";
  height: 50px;
  border-right: 3px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-right: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="out">
    <div class="inner">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="out">
    <div class="inner">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="out">
    <div class="inner">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you want to minimize your html code, I will say no need of out **`div`** like below

```css
#main {
  display: flex
}

.inner:after {
  content: "";
  height: 50px;
  border-right: 3px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-right: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="inner">
    content
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    content
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```